# Brute-force perfect-number algorithm

Tags: haskell, mathematics

I whipped a reasonably fast brute-force perfect number finding function in Haskell, after seeing a similar thing in mathematica.

It works in under 3 seconds when I search up to 1000, but 10000 is too much.

```
isDivisor :: Integral a => a -> a -> Bool
isDivisor n a = mod n a == 0

sumDivisors :: Integral a => a -> a
sumDivisors a =
   foldr (\n -> if isDivisor a n then (+ n) else id) 0 [1..(a `div` 2)]

isPerfect :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPerfect n = n == sumDivisors n

-- The main prime-finding function:
upUntil :: Integral a => a -> [a]
upUntil n = filter isPerfect [1..n]
```

It certainly isn't the fastest, or the most elegant, but I'm unsure how I can improve it.

I would like to concentrate on the `isDivisor` function in particular. Is there a more efficient way of checking for divisibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers), here's a function to calculate the first n perfect numbers:

```
Import Data.Numbers.Primes(primes, isPrime) -- https://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes-0.2.1.0/docs/src/Data-Numbers-Primes.html

-- A perfect number is a number of the form 2p−1× (2p − 1) 
-- where 2p − 1 is a Mersenne prime (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_perfect_numbers)
firstPerfectNumbers :: Int -> [Integer]
firstPerfectNumbers n = 
    take n [2 ^ (x - 1) * (2 ^ x - 1) | x <- primes, isPrime(2 ^ x - 1)]
```

This function returns the first 8 numbers in a second, but slows down after that.

Your original `upUntil` function could be implemented like this:

```
perfectNumbersUpTo :: Integer -> [Integer]
perfectNumbersUpTo n = 
    takeWhile (< n) [2 ^ (x - 1) * (2 ^ x - 1) | x <- primes, isPrime(2 ^ x - 1)]
```

But of course, seeing as there are only 35 perfect numbers with less than 1,000,000 digits and 48 known numbers, if I wanted to use a perfect number in a program I would probably use a precomputed table.

Also, if you aren't using your `upUntil` function to try to find new perfect numbers, or if your program isn't critically dependent on a perfect number of humongous size, then your `isPerfect` function would probably benefit from this:

```
isPerfect n | odd n = False
```

Because it's not known whether odd perfect numbers exist.

Answer (score 7):

### Use backticks

Backticks allow you to put the function name between the values instead of before:

```
isDivisor n a = mod n a == 0
```

becomes:

```
isDivisor n a = n `mod` a == 0
```

### Give less general names

The name `upUntil` tells nothing about perfect numbers, in a tiny script like this this is no problem, but the habit of meningful names will play yo your advantage in  larger scripts

### Do not write wrong comments

Comments don't run, but you are not justified to write wrong comments

```
-- The main prime-finding function:
```

The function does not find primes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's hard to improve `isDivisor`, as it's just a call to the primitive function `mod`. However, there are other areas for improvement.

In particular, going through `[1..(a`div`2)]` is a very inefficient method for listing divisors. A much more efficient method would be to factorize `a` and then compute all its divisors from that (see [Divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function),  in particular the formula specialized for *σ₁(n)*).

So my suggestion would be:

- Generate all primes up to your upper bound.
- Use them to factorize each number in the range.
- Use the formula for *σ₁(n)* to compute the sum of divisors.

See also package [arithmoi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.1.0.1/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Factorisation.html) which implements a lot of such functions.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer based on mersenne primes is unbeatable in speed, but if you want to extend your code for [abundant numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) `sumDivisors n > n` or [deficient numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deficient_number) `... < n`, there are some options left.

### Low-Level optimizations

Since you are asking for speed improvements, here is your code with

```
main = print $ upUntil 10000
```

> $ time ./Main
>   [6,28,496,8128]
>
> real    **0m3.193s**
>   user    0m0.000s
>   sys     0m0.046s

Just by using `Int` like this, time drops to **0.920s**.

```
main = print $ upUntil (10000 :: Int)
```

`mod` handles negative values nicely, here `rem` sufficient and yields another drop to **0.710s**:

```
isDivisor n a = rem n a == 0
```

Changing all functions' type signatures to `Int` does not provide any boost - GHC is already specializing the functions.

### Algorithmic

You can gain a lot by taking also `b = n / a` if `n / a` is integer like this, where you just need to iterate up to the square root:

```
sumDivisors a =
   foldr (\n -> let (q,r) = a `quotRem` n in
       if r==0 then (+ (n+q)) else id) 1
       [2..(floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ a)]
```

(This does not handle perfect squares properly)